# PHPUnit and PHPStorm... ResultPrinter.php Error

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

Whenever I run phpunit tests from PHPStorm I get an error. I have provided more info below.  I am not sure where I have miss configured the setup.

#### My Setup

- Ubuntu
- PHPStorm 8.0.1
- PHPUnit 4.3.4

#### More Info:

PHPUnit.phar is located at `/usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar`. I have setup PHPUnit path directly in PHPStorm. Tests run from bash with no issues. I have also setup my configuration file `phpunit.xml` in PHPUnit, which is located in the root of my project. The `phpunit.xml` file  tells phpunit to load the composer `autoload.php` file.

#### PHPUnit Output:

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /home/mkelley/projects/CompanyName/phpunit.xml
Testing started at 10:33 AM ...
PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/mkelley/projects/CompanyName/phpunit.xml

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method  CompanyNameTests\Boundaries\BoardMemberVotingBoundaryTest::hasExpectationOnOutput() in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 545
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
PHP   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main($exit = *uninitialized*) /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:500
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run($argv = *uninitialized*, $exit = *uninitialized*) /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:243
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun($suite = *uninitialized*, $arguments = *uninitialized*) phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run($result = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:423
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run($result = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:703
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run($result = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:703
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run($test = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:771
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->endTest($test = *uninitialized*, $time = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:760
PHP  10. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->endTest($test = *uninitialized*, $time = *uninitialized*) /home/mkelley/projects/CompanyName/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:378

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I have searched Google and was unable to find a similar issue. I appreciate any help!

#### EDIT

Here is my phpunit.xml file.  PHPStorm is using this as a "Use alternative configuration file"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question in case someone else comes across this issue.

The issue was autoloading PHPUnit via composer and using phpunit.phar. Once I removed the phpunit dependence from composer PHPStorm was able to successfully run all my tests.

Comment: For me the other way worked ... so I removed the phpunit dependency from /usr/bin/phpunit and phpstorm used the correct version from the composer dependency.

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be the autoloading issue. When you bootstrap your app for the test suite you must initialise your autoloader, which doesn't seem to be happening, as something doesn't get found. The easiest way would be to use Composer to manage the PHPUnit dependency and autoload your classes via the `autoload` directive. See the the `psr-4` part in [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Then in your PhpStorm PHPUnit configuration window select `Use custom autoloader` and specify path to your `vendor/autoload.php` script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The issue was using phpunit.phar along with autoloading phpunit via composer.

Comment: This answer may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068516/cannot-extend-controller-test-class/35070800#35070800

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes is better an image...

[image]

As you can see, you can also use your `phpunit.phar` file.

Comment: Thanks @Manolo, I didn't read and my "Path to script" was to the composer.json. not to the vendor/autoload.php. Your image made me re-think :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that you autoloading phpunit via composer, but that in the composer you use an old version of phpUnit. In my case instead of using 4.0.0 I updated to 4.6.*.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same issue with composer and found using the .phar didnt have any issues. Today I've just realised **slaps forehead** it was just caused by installing phpunit via composer and then not reindexing the vendor folder.

I haven't found that I've had this issue previously when installing new packages with composer but for some reason when installing phpunit it hadn't reindexed the vendor folder causing inconsistencies.

Reindex, everything working normally.