# Cannot extend controller test class

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a Base class to be extended by the controller tests:

```
//Base.php
namespace AppBundle\Tests\System;

abstract class Base extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    ...
}
```

But when I try to extend it:

```
//DefaultControllerTest.php
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use AppBundle\Tests\System\Base;

class DefaultControllerTest extends Base
{
    ...
}
```

I get this error:

> /usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /server/project/phpunit.xml /server/project/src/AppBundle/Tests
>   Testing started at 18:36 ...
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\Tests\System\Base' not found in /server/project/src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php on line 7
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

PhpStorm is detecting the `Base` class in `DefaultController.php`, so it does not seem a typo.

This is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
        backupGlobals               = "false"
        backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
        colors                      = "true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
        processIsolation            = "false"
        stopOnFailure               = "false"
        syntaxCheck                 = "false"
        bootstrap                   = "app/bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Tests">
            <directory>src/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app" />
    </php>

    <groups>
        <exclude>
            <group>slow</group>
        </exclude>
    </groups>

    <!-- This is for code coverage -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>app</directory>
            <directory>src</directory>

            <exclude>
                <directory>app/cache/*</directory>

                <file>app/check.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: phpunit do not use composer autoloader I think.

Comment: That thing that PHPStorm detects `Base` class is related only to PHPStorm :). Your `DefaultControllerTest` class doesn't know anything about your `Base` class when you are running tests. You need some kind of autoloader/kernel that would load it for you.

Comment: Thanks @malcolm for giving me the clue.

Comment: Also you, @Ilya Yarkovets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can actually tell phpunit directly to use the composer autoloader:

```
bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
```

Instead of `"web/app_test.php"`

This is for Symfony >= 2.8, for previous versions I think it would be `"vendor/autoload.php"`

Answer (score 2):

As @malcolm and @Ilya Yarkovets suggest, I need to include the testing autoloader. So I've created an `app_test.php` file inside `web` directory with this configuration:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

and changed this line in `phpunit.xml`:

```
bootstrap                   = "web/app_test.php" >
```

I'm not sure yet if `app_test.php` should be modified, but now seems to work as expected.